# Apple Push Notifications Not Working

Tags: push-notification

Im trying to get push notifications to work 100% of the time, i have three test devices, 2 iPads and an iPhone.

I am getting the token using

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenString = deviceToken.hexString;
```

and the extension being

```
extension NSData {
    var hexString: String {
        let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count:self.length)
        return bytes.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.reduce("", combine: { $0 + $1 })
   }
}
```

I then send the string to a server and store the string on a server.

Issue is, when i plug the device into the laptop and run the code via Xcode i get a different token to when i run the app when distributed by testfairy.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you may be running the same app on the same device, Testfairy is probably provisioning the app differently so that will result in a different deviceToken.

That is similar to when an app gets reinstalled, the device token gets reset.